# Обфускатор для .NET

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, обфускация

Хотелось бы услышать мнение, кто имел личный опыт работы с этими продуктами.
Кто чем хорош и что посоветуете для обфусцировать пару проектов (по ~20 сборок в каждой WPF, MEF, Uniti, XML).

- .NET Reactor
- {SmartAssembly}
- CodeVeil

Comment: Мне кажется, в подавляющем большинстве случаем обфускация не нужна. Критически важные алгоритмы (если такие есть) можно написать на подходящем нативном языке. Бизнес-логика вашего приложения специфична только для него, и красть её нет смысла, потому что за то время, которое нужно, чтобы разобраться в ней, квалифицированная команда разработчиков напишет такое же с нуля, а то и лучше. Красть контролы совсем уж бессмысленно.

Comment: Обфускация "для галочки" или "на всякий" действительно не нужна. Работал с СмартАсс - приятное впечатление, высокие показатели, "сложно" взломать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юзали .NET Reactor для довольно крупного проекта (400К исходников, до 50 классов (само собой с вложенным наследованием), до 10 форм) - основная задача, чтоб всякие разные своими ручками не шарились.

После заколбашивания работало стабильно, вылетов замечено не было, особых проблем с быстродействием также.

Есть ряд прикольных опций вроде препятствования анализу декомпилятором, попытки пересобрать в нативный код с прямой линковкой к библиотекам .NETа... Это даже работает, но на публичную версию мы применять не рискнули)

Comment: Какая-то мутная цель применения, если честно. Чисто для себя интересно, что вы скрывали от этих "всяких разных со своими ручками"? Лицензирование? Доступ на сервер? Секретные алгоритмы или инновационные решения? К автору тот же вопрос.

Comment: Программа разработана на основе научной методики, и программ такого рода нет.
Поэтому заказчик требует защиту.

Comment: @Event, если ценность научной методики состоит в математическом алгоритме, то только нативный код. Потому что отреверсить алгоритм из машинного кода значительно сложнее, чем из dotnet байт-кода (в случае обхода всех этих антиреверсинговых фич), который без проблем восстанавливается в исходник на любом dotnet языке.

Comment: @Flammable: Хм. Я бы не был настолько категоричен. Если мы и вправду хотим, чтобы алгоритм никто не раскопал, надо не отдавать бинарники, а класть их на сервер и организовывать API доступа. Но ТС же не хочет усложнять себе жизнь, он лишь хочет, чтобы заказчик был счастлив. Если для этого достаточно слегка пообфусцировать код, почему бы и нет? Глупость заказчика -- проблема заказчика. Переписывать всё на нативный язык геморно.

Comment: @VladD, пожалуй, соглашусь.

Comment: @wind... Как по мне, единственная объективная цель. 

Если я хочу открыть мой софт всем и вся, я пользую GPL) 

Если я сильно не хочу открыть код, я его не публикую и поставляю даже в виде ЕХЕшника, только в виде он-лайн сервиса.

А так, чтоб разные люди с низким IQ не лазили туда всякими reflector'ами. 

Когда жил на съемной квартире, моего там были только носки, сосики и презервативы - но дверь я ж зачем-то закрывал.

Comment: @SilverIce... Аналогия с дверью не очень подходящая, так как она защищает в первую очередь жизнь хозяина, что намного ценней любых материальных благ. Что касается людей с низким АЙКЮ, то им не поможет ни один рефлектор, а вообще ваша позиция мне понятна, спасибо.