# Обфускация кода C# при использовании MVVM Light

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Здравствуйте! Хочу защитить программу на C# (WPF, .NET 4.5.2) обфускатором.
Дело в том, что используя фреймворк MVVM Light после обфускации (к примеру, ConfuserEx, Obfuscar) программа просто вылетает, тогда как без использования MVVM Light обфускация проходит нормально и программа запускается.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, *актуальный* бесплатный обфускатор, если еще какой-нибудь знаете, т.к. те, которые нахожу в Google, уже устарели, либо не поддерживают даже .NET 4.0.
Нужно ли обфусцировать библиотеки, на которые ссылается программа? Та же MVVM Light.

Я понимаю, что любая программа взламывается, но хочется хотя бы базовую защиту, чтобы ее не взломали за 2 минуты в Reflector или DotPeek.

Спасибо.

Comment: Я тоже раньше страдал такой фигней. Но, я успешно переборол это, и моя программистская жизнь стала намного легче:) Поверьте, это бестолковое опасение. Его надо отпустить и забыть. Ничего интересного в ваших алгоритмах и коде для хакеров нет. Вы ведь в коде не храните пароли и коды доступа? Ну и славно.

Comment: @Bulson, алгоритмы здесь ни при чем, если у C# код как на ладони. Механизм активации в открытую оставлять не буду, т.к. программа коммерческая.

Comment: Механизм активации можно сделать подключаемой библиотекой, которая написана, скажем, на плюсах.

Comment: @Bulson, тоже верно, но если код программы C# будет доступен, то можно просто отменить подключение к библиотеке активации и вставить результат, что программа активирована. Для этого даже не придется дизассемблировать библиотеку. Поэтому и хочется защитить фрагменты кода, потому что все равно в коде будет видно, что происходит после нажатия, например, "Справка->Активировать продукт...".

Comment: Да, в этом вы правы. Но, в тоже время, я про это и говорил:) Это напоминает хождение по кругам ада. Защищаешь одно, но вылезает незащищенность другого. Обфускатор тем и хорош, что дает защиту не программному коду, а программисту! Дарит программисту чувство уверенности и успокоения.

Comment: А что за механизм активации у вас предполагается? Если после нажатия на "Активировать" происходит обращение к удаленному сервису, ничего в этом страшного нет, что кто-то увидит данный код, сервис то все равно не доступен для него.

Comment: @sp7, суть даже не в механизме активации, суть в том, чтобы начинающие хакеры не взломали код, чтобы программа сразу себя считала зарегистрированной и никуда не обращалась. Продвинутые взломают любую вещь (яркий пример - миллиарды долларов в Denuvo, однако... :))),, но защищаю код не от них.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "начинающие хакеры не взломали код"? Да даже если и взломают, это сильно усложнит вам жизнь?

Comment: @sp7, не получу денег, т.к. я индивидуальный разработчик )

Comment: Ну если вы индивидуальный разработчик, то реализовывать активацию на стороне клиента не лучшая идея. Я бы все-таки рассматривал для этих целей, создание какого-то стороннего сервиса. Или с этим есть какая-то проблема?

Comment: @sp7, я рассматривал вариант онлайн-активации, просто пока не знаю, как это лучше реализовать.

Comment: Реализация, это вторично. У вас само видение есть, как ваш процесс активации должен осуществляться?

Comment: @sp7, да, видение есть. Это и привязка к железу, например (не ко всему, т.е. жесткий диск, к примеру, не участвует в привязке). Плюс погуглил еще, и нашел, что нужно сразу не выдавать проверку, а подсунуть фейковые функции, второй этап проверки можно, например, через 5 дней сделать и т.п. Однако все это пустышка, если не защищать исходный код C#. Думаю, если не смогу нормально защитить код C#, написать все на Qt C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из своего [опыта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/188620/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-net) хочу поделиться тем, что бесплатные обфускатор это обычный Renamer, который переводит название (переменных/свойств/классов и т.д.) в нечитабельный вид.

Из бесплатных и более качественных возможен вам подайдут

- [Obfuscar](http://obfuscar.codeplex.com)
- [Dotfuscator Community Edition](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/compare-editions)

Из платных использовал [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm), который умел не только обфусцировать, но и еще можно было привязывать exe к конкретной машине или задавать определённый срок после которой exe не запускался.

В 2013 году из .NET Reactor приходилась исключать некоторый сборки т.к. он ломал их и программа просто падала, возможно это было связано с сериализацией, но с нашим MVVM фраемворком он дружил (Prims 4.1). Возможно сейчас дела по луче.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал свою сборку ConfuserEx, убрал аттрибуты ConfuserEx, сменил ключ шифрования и решил заодно обфусцировать библиотеки MVVM Light вместе главной программой - результат - программа не вылетает. Правда, антивирус ругается, но это из-за Anti-Tamper.